# Print all UTF-8 character of specific range to utf-8 encoded text

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8

i have this code to print all character in the range between 1536 to 1791 (Arabic characters )

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{

int t;
t=1536;
do
{
printf("%c",t);
t++;
}
while(t<=1791);
}
```

the sample output is

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~€پ‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰ٹ‹Œچژڈگ‘’“”
```

some of character is unreadable because it should be stored in utf-8 text file so it can be readable

any advice how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Learn what Unicode is and what UTF-8 is and how I/O works in C. There are lots of things wrong with your code...

Comment: The given sample output doesn't list characters in the range 1536 to 1791. There are only a few Arabic characters included and their presence suggests that the characters 0-255 were printed to a terminal window in a non-UTF-8 encoding and then copy-pasted out to this website, which uses UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Unicode* assigns a meaning to (some of) the numbers 0 – 0x10FFFF. We call those numbers with meaning "code points", and their associated meaning "characters".

*UTF-8* is a binary format for expressing Unicode characters as a sequence of bytes. It is a variable-length encoding in which the characters whose codepoint value is below 0x80 take one byte, the remaining ones below 0x800 take two bytes, the remaining ones below 0x10000 take three bytes, and all others four bytes.

A partial implementation of UTF-8 that only works for the first 2048 code points (which covers your use case) might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void utf8print(unsigned int cp)
{
    if (cp < 0x80)
    {
        printf("%c", cp);
    }
    else if (cp < 0x800)
    {
        printf("%c%c", 0xC0 + cp / 0x40, 0x80 + cp % 0x40);
    }
    // you should implement the three- and four-byte cases, too.
}

int main()
{
    // characters below 32 are "not printable"
    for (unsigned int i = 32; i != 2048; ++i)
    {
        printf("U+%04X: ", i);
        utf8print(i);
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
}
```

This just writes raw bytes to the standard output; it is *your* responsibility to either set your output terminal to understand UTF-8, or to capture the output in a file and open it in an application that handles UTF-8.

Comment: could you please explain me what is this code do printf("%c%c", 0xC0 + cp / 0x40, 0x80 + cp % 0x40); Thanks

Comment: @user2999200: It implements UTF-8. Once you learn what UTF-8 is, it should be clear what this code does.